# How to set a specific order of deployment in Maven?

Tags: maven

Having a project with multiple submodules, how do I specify which module is the first to deploy, which is the second and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This order is same as build order in reactor (`deploy` of module is done just after it's packaged, module after module), so it depends on dependencies between modules. If there's more than one module with the same "priority" within reactor build order, order in `pom.xml` is used then.

So, in general, modules with no dependencies on other modules will be build somewhere in the beginning and modules with many dependencies on other modules will be build somewhere in the end.

Comment: OK. And among the modules with same priority - how do I set the first?

Comment: By "priority" I mean the situation where many modules are equal in sense of dependencies on other modules. And as I said, then `pom.xml` order (`<module>` tags) is used.

Comment: And you do not know of any additional parameters that override the order? I have an alphabetical order that I'd like to keep ;)

Comment: AFAIK there's no other mechanism of order prediction. But if you have your dependencies set right, there should be no problem about it. What's wrong in your case exactly?

Comment: I have a runtime dependency, but no compile one.

Comment: Hmmm, it's really weird, because `runtime` scope does the same effect on build order as `compile`, at least with Maven 3.0.4.

Comment: It's not a maven dependency but a RMI runtime dependency :) After deploy, one module contacts the second.. But the second is not yet deployed.